# How to compare duplicated values and filter out unwanted ones in a R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I made up a test data frame like this:

```
gene <- as.factor(c('A','B','B','B','C','C','D'))
location <- as.integer(c(1,4,5,6,2,3,9))
df <- data.frame(gene, location)

> df
  gene location
1    A        1
2    B        4
3    B        5
4    B        6
5    C        2
6    C        3
7    D        9
```

I would like to keep unique genes A, B, C, D, and filter out duplicated genes with non-highest location. (e.g. for gene B, only B with location 6 would be kept; for gene C, only C with location 3 would be kept).

So the end result should be like:

```
  gene location
1    A        1
4    B        6
6    C        3
7    D        9
```

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `aggregate()` or `ave()` to do that, i.e.,

```
dfout <- aggregate(location ~ gene, df, FUN = max)
```

or

```
dfout <- unique(within(df,location <- ave(location,gene,FUN = max)))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  gene location
1    A        1
2    B        6
3    C        3
4    D        9
```

Comment: I wonder what should I specify the "~ gene" here if I have a larger data frame with not just two columns?

Comment: @Helena then you can use `dfout <- aggregate(. ~ gene, df, FUN = max)`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a data frame that has more than gene and location, you can try:

```
df = df[order(df$gene,-df$location),]
df[!duplicated(df$gene),]
```

Comment: Seems that it does not work in larger dataset, but I fixed it by adding one more line like:
`df <- df[order(-df$location),]`
`index <- duplicated(df$gene)`
`df <- df[!index,]`
Although it looks the same as what you suggest.

Comment: Yes. Just do df = df[order(-df$location); df <- df[!duplicated(df$gene),]

Comment: Your example data frame is small, so I just showed the solution above, as it is not costly to sort two columns. Useful to state that in your question.